# I get empty version when I upload react native iOS app to App Store Connect

Tags: xcode, react-native, app-store-connect

Hello I tried to upload react native iOS app to App Store. the upload is succefull but when I try to see the build in testFlight it show like this
[image]

as you see it show me the version but inside it is empty. then after  one minute even the version number disappear and it asks me to upload again. I uploaded it many time but still the same thing

Answer (score 0):

The version disappears if there is another upload with the same version number. Change the version and try to upload the app again.

Comment: have you fixed it in the meantime?

Comment: Yes, I found out that the problem was with one of the npm packages(React native Firebase npm Packages) and it was not letting the app to build In AppStoreConnect. And if you are interested I will explain more

Comment: Hey rawand, I'm having a similiar issue, and I am using firebase for my React Native. What was your solution?

Answer (score 0):

sorry for the late answer. the issue was the firebase npm packages were not the latest version and it was causing an issue during uploading. So remove all firebase npm packages and install them again after that upload the app.